# Tax assessment paid last year

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction

Last year I had to pay a income tax assessment for a W2 I forgot to report from 2009.  Can't I report that on my taxes this season?  Where would I put this in H&R Tax at Home (Taxcut)?

Answer (score 2):

On your 2011 Federal income tax return, you cannot *deduct* the amount paid in 2011 for Federal taxes that were due with your 2009 return, and you don't report them anywhere on your 2011 return either. If the Federal assessment for 2009 triggered a change in your State income tax return for 2009, and in 2011 you paid additional State income tax for 2009, then, if you are itemizing deductions, this State payment can be deducted on Schedule A along with the other State income tax payments for 2011.